# Type_index use, destruction, and synchronization in the state machine implementation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In an ongoing project there is a need to have multiple finite state machines implemented. A common layer would be nice so that similar checks and balances can be developed. The state machines' requirements are diverse enough so I wanted to have data types to be determined outside of the FSM template as a user responsibility. Also I wanted to have persistent data totally controlled by an FSM implementation author. Finally, thread-safety is a must for state transition in the template.

That resulted in what I think is a lean state transition code. The idea is that the FSM template should be both specialized *and* wrapped into a usable outer class by an FSM implementer. That wrapper class will be a full specific FSM implementation. The FSM template uses data types and logic defined outside of it, but those states and data should not be visible outside of that final wrapper implementation of an FSM.

A few questions remain (I am very green by C++ standards). Here they are:

1. Is using `type_index` as a map key in this case an oddity or goes along with `type_index` design intent? Is it unique enough for this purpose?
2. Is that right that the "magic" of `shared_ptr` will automatically and properly destroy all data instantiated in the wrapper class?
3. Are there destuction order issue somewhere in this template and implementation?
4. Is there a way to test proper destruction and it's order?
5. Is there a way (or a reasonable need) to test that state transitions actually synchronize in the `FSM::operator()` method?

Below is the template itself and the main Turnstile class, toughly implementing that from [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Example:_a_turnstile). The other six implementation files with specific types and state logic are at [my GitHub FSM repository](https://github.com/didenko/FSM/tree/c6b80473071cf906bb86dc525ac7d991b9834e01) if needed.

The FSM template below takes a vector of logic reacting to messages, with the head of the vector defining the initial state. It wraps each message actor in a state object, attaching state data an plumbing to it. When the FSM template runs a state it can also do sanit checks that the returned "next" state key is valied (future, left out for briefness here).

Here is the template:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <typeindex>
#include <mutex>

namespace tools {

  template <typename Message, typename Content>
  class FSM {

  public:


    class React {
    public:
      virtual std::type_index operator()( const Message & msg, std::shared_ptr<Content> ) {
        return std::type_index(typeid(this));
      };
    };


    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<React>> Flux;


    FSM( Flux & flux, std::shared_ptr<Content> ctnt )
    : current( std::type_index( typeid( *( flux.at(0) ) ) ) )
    , content( ctnt )
    {
      for ( auto rct: flux ) {
        states[ std::type_index( typeid( *rct ) ) ] = State( rct, content );
      };
    };

    void operator()( const Message & msg ) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( fsm_mutex );
      current = states.at( current )( msg );
    };


  private:


    class State {

    public:
      State( std::shared_ptr<React> rct, std::shared_ptr<Content> ctnt )
      : content( ctnt ), react( rct ) {};

      State() : content( nullptr ), react( nullptr ) {};

      std::type_index operator()( const Message & message ) {
        return (*react)( message, content );
      }

    private:
      std::shared_ptr<Content> content;
      std::shared_ptr<React> react;
    };


    std::mutex fsm_mutex;

    std::shared_ptr<Content> content;
    std::type_index current;
    std::map<std::type_index, State> states;
  };
}
```

The implementation class header:

```
#pragma once

#include "TurnstileTypes.h"

namespace tools {
  namespace test {
    namespace fsm {

      // Implementation of the Turnstile FSM example from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine#Example:_a_turnstile
      // Added RESET event to better test state.
      class Turnstile {
      public:

        Turnstile(void);

        void operator()( const TurnstileEvent & msg );

        unsigned long Pushed();
        unsigned long Paid();
        std::string Now();

      private:

        TurnstileFSM::Flux flux;
        std::unique_ptr<TurnstileFSM> fsm;
        std::shared_ptr<TurnstileData> stats;
      };

    }
  }
}
```

The implementation class body:

```
#include "TurnstileTypes.h"
#include "TurnstileLocked.h"
#include "TurnstileUnlocked.h"
#include "Turnstile.h"

namespace tools {
  namespace test {
    namespace fsm {

      Turnstile::Turnstile(void)
      : stats( std::make_shared<TurnstileData>() )
      {
        flux.push_back( std::make_shared<Locked>() );
        flux.push_back( std::make_shared<Unlocked>() );
        fsm = std::unique_ptr<TurnstileFSM>( new TurnstileFSM( flux, stats ) );
      };

      void Turnstile::operator()( const TurnstileEvent & msg ) {
        (*fsm)( msg );
      };


      unsigned long Turnstile::Pushed() { return stats->pushes; };
      unsigned long Turnstile::Paid()   { return stats->coins;  };
      std::string Turnstile::Now()      { return stats->state_name; };

    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for the answers!

[update 131120] It may be helpful to mention, that `FSM.h` is not meant to be a library with a "public interface". More so it is a boilerplate code to get an FSM author going. The actual user FSM interface is defined by that FSM implementation - in the attached example it is in `Turnstile.h`. As such, the FSM.h template kept be very short, and intended to be read and understood by an FSM author.

I would also expect them (myself for now) to understand the documented pitfalls of the template - like the fact that sending a message to any FSM while it is in a `State()()`method will dead-lock. Which can be caused by a chain of calls. [Thanks to Florian Philipp comment on Google+](https://plus.google.com/+VladDidenko/posts/4Aijg6v1wvg) for pointing that out.

There is also an intent to have least knowledge in FSM about `Message` and `Content` types, so that FSM authors have most flexibility while implementing - that includes getting information out of content by something like accessors. That flexibility comes with responsibility of not changing the content.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use [Meta State Machine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/pr01.html) ?

Comment: No third party libraries yet allowed on the target codebase. Also the solution above is designed to minimize refactoring there.

Comment: @maxim-yegorushkin (mention for the comment above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note, if you know your state machine at compile time, it maybe easier to use Boost.MSM like Maxim mentioned.

Now to your questions.

1. I believe the type_index was designed for use with map and unordered_map so you're using it as designed.
2. shared_ptr will correctly cleanup, however, consider avoiding it here. It looks like there's really no shared ownership. For content, decide if FSM or the user code owns it and either use unique_ptr or raw ptr/reference for FSM::content, the rest can be raw ptrs/refs. I would also make React be owned by the FSM. typedef Flux to be a vector<unique_ptr<React>> and move the ownerships into the state object.
3. Destruction order should be fine here.
4. I'm not aware of an easy way to test correctness of destruction order but all your destructors are trivial so the order doesn't really matter.
5. Your public interface consists of one method that has been serialized via a mutex -- there's no real need to test that it will synchronize. If the user touches React subclassed objects, that can also lead to trouble, however, if you move them (instead of share them) into the FSM, it won't be an issue. Also, please not that content can be read/updated from both the inside and outside of your FSM which can lead to synchronization issues.

Comment: 1. Got it. 2. Got it. I am having some trouble making Flux into vector of unique_ptr - somewhere there is copy involved I do not see yet. 3. Thanks. 4. Thank you. 5. Got it. I keep thinking about the content. Someone else pointed that as well at [the related Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+VladDidenko/posts/foFNXtveGXy).

Comment: @VladDidenko if a copy c'tor/assignment is getting hit, you probably need to wrap the object you're passing with std::move.